# How to add fields to the ActiveReports 10 Forms ReportExplorer Control

Tags: activereports

I am using ActiveReports 10 in a c# WinForms application.

I am creating a form where the user can design report.  I want to pre-populate the report explorer control with a list of fields that the user can drag onto the report designer control.

I don't know how to create the field entries in the report explorer control.

Note that I do not want to use the toolbox control to drag textboxes or labels onto the forms for the user to configure.  I want them to be able to drag on pre-configured "things" that print out specific values.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

just set the data source and query of your report and the report will populate the fields tree automatically.